# How to normalize data of a generic HTTP request for the purpose of signing

Tags: protocol-design, reference-request, mac, standards

I am working on [PowerAuth 2.0](https://github.com/lime-company/lime-security-powerauth/), a solution for counter-based signing of HTTP requests (for the purpose of mobile banking). One of the tasks that I solved somehow but I am still not happy with the solution is the HTTP request normalization. (Use of HTTP is a condition, since this is the most realistic usage scenario these days.)

Basically, I need to answer the question "How do I turn any incoming HTTP request into a normalized signature base string so that I can compute a signature?" (my current approach is [here](https://github.com/lime-company/lime-security-powerauth/blob/master/powerauth-docs/source/signatures.md#normalized-data-for-http-requests)).

Are there any standard ways to solve this task?

If not, how would you go around the issue? Should I include HTTP headers or focus only on URL, method and body? Should I pay attention to the corner cases, such as duplicate GET parameters? etc.

Comment: It seems this question is better suited for [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), since it is concerned with how to deal with the internals of HTTP in the context of a security protocol. There is basically no cryptographic theory involved, which is what this site is about.

Comment: @yyyyyyy, OTOH, it is a question about cryptographic standards. I'd keep it here.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the tags - I agree this is more of an auxiliary topic...